# Can I read the cuepoints of an external mp3 file in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3

I want to add some **cuepoints** (or any kind of markers) in an **mp3** file in Adobe Audition then to load this mp3 file in **Flash (AS3)** to a sound object and, somehow, to **get those cuepoints** (their names and their positions).

All I found is workarounds for how to add and get the cuepoints in Flash, after the mp3 is loaded, not to have them previously embeded in the mp3 file, as I want to.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think cuepoints are actually stored in MP3 file. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: I already did the first part. I saved and closed the file, I reopened it and the cuepoints are there. I saw no other file after saving, so I guess they are stored in the mp3.

Comment: how are you playing the file?

Comment: I'm loading it as a sound in Flash AS3 and attaching it to a soundchannel. I want to be able to list the cuepoints names and to jump on them when clciking them. I know I can use a second file for this, to store the cuepoints, but first I want to know if this is possible without a second file.